# How to stop csv from converting string to number in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have used a PL/SQL code to export data to *csv* file.The code is similar to below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_to_csv IS
  v_file   UTL_FILE.file_type;
  v_string VARCHAR2(4000);

  CURSOR c_emp IS
  SELECT empno, ename, deptno, sal, comm 
    FROM emp;
BEGIN
  v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('CSVDIR', 'empdata.csv', 'w', 1000);

  -- if you do not want heading then remove below two lines v_string := 'Emp Code, Emp Name, Dept, Salary, Commission'; UTL_FILE.put_line (v_file, v_string);

  FOR cur IN c_emp LOOP
    v_string := cur.empno || ',' || cur.ename || ',' || cur.deptno || ',' ||cur.sal || ',' || cur.comm;
  
    UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file, v_string);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(v_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

But one column which datatype is varchar2 is getting converted to number and hence loss of data is occuring.Could anyone please tell me how to stop the conversion?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to express which that column is, and why you think so ?

Comment: this is a sample code ,I cannot reveal the actual code .But a column with data type varchar2(50) is getting converted to number automatically and the value is getting trimmed with zeroes . When the same file is opened in notepad++ ,the value is getting displayed correctly .

Comment: only in csv file ,the value is getting trimmed.

Comment: Well, it's expected for the replier people to see a minimal example(of course veiling your actual code) to be able to reproduce your case, and please edit the question with such stuff rather than commenting.

Comment: This code has only one implicit type conversion, where you concatenate everything into a single string. There's no string to number conversion. Please, describe why do you think it is here?

Comment: Try enclosing that value within double quotes.

Comment: There is probably no conversion problem at all if you can see all the data when you open the file in Notepad++,  as you said. If there were any losss of data during the process there is no way that Notepad++ could do the inserts of the missing data. What do you check the data with - other than Notepad++. Maybe you are opening it with excel and excel does the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no conversion and/or data loss at all. You can test it if you read the file you created. The result should be the same as you see it when you open it in Notepad++. If it's true that Notepad++ shows all the data then there's nothing lossed. So, create the file and read it afterwards. Compare the data with the result and you will know.

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE read_csv IS
  v_file   UTL_FILE.file_type;
  v_string VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
  v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('CSVDIR', 'empdata.csv', 'r', 1000);
  LOOP
      UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_file, v_string);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_string);
  END LOOP;
  
  UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(v_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
    END IF;
END;
-- 
--  R e s u l t
--
-- anonymous block completed
-- 7369,SMITH,20,800,
-- 7499,ALLEN,30,1600,300
-- 7521,WARD,30,1250,500
-- 7566,JONES,20,2975,
-- 7654,MARTIN,30,1250,1400
-- 7698,BLAKE,30,2850,
-- 7782,CLARK,10,2450,
-- 7788,SCOTT,20,3000,
-- 7839,KING,10,5000,
-- 7844,TURNER,30,1500,0
-- 7876,ADAMS,20,1100,
-- 7900,JAMES,30,950,
-- 7902,FORD,20,3000,
-- 7934,MILLER,10,1300,
```